# Redirect all URLs except one

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have this URL:
`www.domain.com/old/`

I want to redirect all the URLs like `www.domain.com/old/xxxx` to:
`www.domain.com/new/xxxx`

Right now, this is working OK. I have this in my *.htacces*:
`RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ new/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

It's redirecting everything, but I want to keep the `www.domain.com/old/`
I mean, I want the root (`www.domain.com/old/`) to keep being `www.domain.com/old/`

Right now, what is happening is that `www.domain.com/old` goes to `www.domain.com/new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.*` (0 or more characters) to `.+` (1 or more characters):

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.+)$ new/$1 [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or clear browser cache completely.